# Rendered fonts have wrong url - Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel-mix

My sass has has a font.scss file which has the following

```
@font-face {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "TT Norms Pro Regular";
  src: local("TT Norms Pro Regular"), url("TT Norms Pro Regular.woff") format("woff");
  }
```

And the fonts live in the same directory as the sass file. Example being;

```
  /05_fonts
   - fonts.scss
   - TT Norms Pro Regular.woff
```

My main scss imports the above fonts.scss.

My issue is that a fonts folder created at the root of the directory and not in `dist/assets/fonts/` where I need it to be.

From researching the issue I found that I can add `mix.config.fileLoaderDirs.fonts = 'dist/assets/fonts';` to my `webpack.mix.js` file. This does pull the fonts into `dist/assets/fonts/`. But the resulting css is then;

```
  @font-face {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: "TT Norms Pro Regular";
    src: local("TT Norms Pro Regular"), url("/dist/assets/fonts/TT Norms Pro Regular.woff?2dbc9dffb1b3db6d23806b49fc286edf") format("woff");
  }
```

Which isn't correct, it needs to be `url("/assets/fonts/TT Norms Pro Regular.woff?2dbc9dffb1b3db6d23806b49fc286edf")`

Upon adding `mix.setResourceRoot('dist')` and then making `mix.config.fileLoaderDirs.fonts = '/assets/fonts';`. Creates a `assets/fonts` folder in the root. Again not correct.

How can I get the fonts into `dist/assets/fonts` with the correct css `url("/dist/assets/fonts/TT Norms Pro Regular.woff")`?

Comment: The last url is a mistake, should be `url("/assets/fonts/TT Norms Pro Regular.woff")`

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out…

```
mix.setPublicPath('dist');
mix.setResourceRoot('/');
```